# Is there a function getting a message by id in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I use a telegram bot to send and edit messages later. I have a list of message ids that were sent already. Due to some exceptions, some messages are not edited and left in the initial state. Is there any way to get the message by id, so text can be checked and edited?

I know, that I can edit messages by ids straight away, but this could lead to various problems (too many requests, editing correct messages, etc). So I want to check messages before editing. I've tried to search a function that can do that in the `python-telegram-bot` library, but no luck.

Messages are sent to the user directly.

`Python-telegram-bot==10.1.0`

Comment: do u aware of time limit to edit msg

Comment: @SmartManoj Yeah, I am. It doesn't matter for my bot. It should only edit recent messages.

Comment: Due to some exceptions ?

Comment: @SmartManoj they mainly happen because time to time I get SSLError from tg package. It happens because I've been using tg with multiprocessing module. I had similar SSLError with CCXT package, but I've solved it by recreating ccxt instance inside each process. Some other exceptions happen, but they are not related to the tg package.

Comment: Store the id for which exceptions arrived and process later

Comment: @SmartManoj great idea! I will try it out! Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to use mtproto to get a message by id from a bot. (on python there is Telethon and Pyrogram as libraries)

Comment: @painor I will check them, thank you!